# How to import onClick in element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add an onclick in and a button tag over jquery

```
<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play" tabindex="0"></button>
<img id="loadingImage" src="preoader.gif" style="visibility:hidden">
```

I need it for this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openImage(){
if ( document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility == 'visible' ) 
{
document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility='hidden';
} else {
document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility='visible';
}}
</script>
```

Comment: seeing how you are trying to switch your visibility, I would highly recommend you create a css class for this. You can then use `.toggleClass()`. This would be cleaner and will allow you to add more functionality in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add events like this:

```
$('#buttonid').on("click", function(){
    //do something here like calling openImage();
});
```

you only need to give your button a unique id like this :

```
<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play" tabindex="0" id="buttonid"></button>
```

EDIT:
if you can not edit the button tag then you may need a different selector.
You can try to get a parent attribute to fetch the right child like this :

```
$('.parentclass button').on("click", function(){
    //do something here like calling openImage();
});
```

or something like this

```
$('.parentclass div button').on("click", function(){
    //do something here like calling openImage();
});
```

EDIT SOLUTION:

```
$(".mejs-play button").on("click", function(){
    openImage();
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why you cant do this ? you can also create a different selector

Comment: Because I use wordpress and I can not make changes to this:https://imgur.com/a/rlaLOuL

Comment: Then pleas append your html code to the question so we can help you further than just guessing.

Comment: `<div class="mejs-button mejs-playpause-button mejs-play"><button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play" tabindex="0"></button></div>`

Comment: Then i would suggest that you use some selector like this : $(".mejs-play button").on("click", function(){ openImage();});

Comment: Sorry, I'm noob for coding xd, where to put this `$(".mejs-play button").on("click", function(){
    openImage();
});`

Comment: In your script, at the very end. Pleas Note that you need to include jquery before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").on("click", function(){
    var img = $("#loadingImage");
    if(img.is(":visible")) {
      img.css({"display" : "none"})
    } else {
      img.css({"display" : "block"})
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn">Click Here</button>
<img id="loadingImage" src="https://b-digital.info/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/preoader.gif">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the html code, you can try using some of the attribute value for the selection part of the jQuery, like in next example:

```
$("button[title='Play']").click(function()
{
    // Just for debugging on the console.
    console.log("Click detected on PLAY button");

    // Call the openImage() method.
    openImage();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake here is trying to mix native js with JQuery. 
When you select an item with lets say `let item = document.getWhatever` then you cant
use Jquery functions on this `item` so you have to select it from the beginning on with JQuery's method `let item = $(#myItem)`.
Afterwards you can use Jquery functionallity to add an onclick event.

Either by setting the onclick as attribute like this:

```
item.attr('onclick', 'doStuff()');
```

or by using the `.click()` like so:

```
item.click(function() {
    doStuff
});
```

Answer (score -1):

based on your example you can add:

```
onClick="openImage();"
```

event handler on your button:

```
<button type="button" onClick="openImage();" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play" tabindex="0"></button>
```

Try it on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmddqR).